# Generic that prevents circular references

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is there a way to create a generic that prevents circular variables?
This should work regardless of depth or circular reference type, not just for T itself...

So far I got this:

```
export type IsEqual<A, B> =
    (<G>() => G extends A ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<G>() => G extends B ? 1 : 2)
    ? true
    : false;

    
type DisallowCircular<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: true extends IsEqual<T[K], T> ? never : T[K]
};

function noCircularAllowed<T extends DisallowCircular<T>>(a: T) {

}

class Foo {
    abc: string;
    circular: Foo;

    constructor() {
        this.abc = "Hello";
        this.circular = this;
    }
}

const foo = new Foo()

noCircularAllowed(foo)
```

Which successfully disallows foo as an input as it has a circular dependency to itself.

Edit 2:
I see that my question was a bit confusing, changed it for clarity, not just assignments, also prevent passing it to a function etc.

Edit 3:
Jcalz correctly stated that this will also catch recursive values and not just self references, which isn't the desired behavior, now that I understand my mistake I realized why this is currently impossible.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Preventing circular references in an object

Comment: lol, yes but what will you do with the un-circulared type ?

Comment: Know it safe to put into JSON.stringify for example, among other things, I want to make a "Serializable" type, but it has alot more use cases then that

Comment: Whether it is safe to `JSON.stringify` depends also on whether the objects do not have a `.toJSON()` method that throws… Which you cannot know or describe in the type.

Comment: If you want to explicitly declare that some of your entities are safe to serialise, you however mark them with a [tag type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895) and then require that tag type in your input. This will require the author of a class to declare their type as safe.

Comment: As I already said, there are a lot of use cases for this, you are taking one edge case for it, a generic type that checks for it and disallows it would be the optimal solution.

Comment: So you're not checking for circular *references*, but recursive *types*?  That's different (and you should probably change the title to reflect that).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. TypeScript has a structural typesystem, it cannot express object identity or know about circular references.
However, if you don't use `any` but properly type all the properties of your object, it will at least make it harder to do so accidentally.

Comment: Right, the type system doesn't model value identity, so there's no handle you can grab onto to prevent circular references.